# JRuby / Warbler / GlassFish - (NameError) uninitialized constant ApplicationController::SessionsHelper

Tags: jruby, glassfish-3, warbler

Really Short Story:
I'm incredibly frustrated by this issue

---

Short Story:
JRuby-1.7.2 building to a .war using Warbler (1.3.8) deploying to a glassfish v3 server. I can build on my machine and everything works fine, however when I try to build with Jenkins, the war gives the following error when trying to load the first page:

**org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (NameError) uninitialized constant ApplicationController::SessionsHelper**

---

Long Story:
Build script on our Jenkins server:

```
#path to rvm
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
# Use the correct ruby
rvm use "jruby-1.7.2@webadmin"
# Set "fail on error" in bash
set -e
# build
bundle update
warble compiled war
```

---

Error log from Glassfish....which I hope has enough info.

[#|2013-05-31T17:10:14.634-0400|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC1412: WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():INFO: pool was empty - getting new application instance|#]

[#|2013-05-31T17:10:25.181-0400|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC1412: WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():An exception happened during JRuby-Rack startup
uninitialized constant ApplicationController::SessionsHelper
--- System
jruby 1.7.4 (1.9.3p392) 2013-05-16 2390d3b on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_27-b27 [linux-amd64]
Time: 2013-05-31 17:10:25 -0400
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2
jruby.home: classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home

--- Context Init Parameters:
com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration = true
com.sun.faces.validateXml = true
public.root = /
rails.env = production

--- Backtrace
NameError: uninitialized constant ApplicationController::SessionsHelper

--- RubyGems
Gem.dir: /opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/myDomain/applications/web-admin/WEB-INF/gems
Gem.path:
/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/myDomain/applications/web-admin/WEB-INF/gems
Activated gems:
  bundler-1.3.5
  rake-10.0.4
  i18n-0.6.1
  multi_json-1.7.4
  activesupport-3.2.13
  builder-3.0.4
  activemodel-3.2.13
  erubis-2.7.0
  journey-1.0.4
  rack-1.4.5
  rack-cache-1.2
  rack-test-0.6.2
  hike-1.2.2
  tilt-1.4.1
  sprockets-2.2.2
  actionpack-3.2.13
  mime-types-1.23
  polyglot-0.3.3
  treetop-1.4.12
  mail-2.5.4
  actionmailer-3.2.13
  arel-3.0.2
  tzinfo-0.3.37
  activerecord-3.2.13
  activeresource-3.2.13
  gyoku-1.0.0
  nokogiri-1.5.9-java
  akami-1.2.0
  bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1-java
  sass-3.2.9
  bootstrap-sass-2.3.1.2
  will_paginate-3.0.4
  bootstrap-will_paginate-0.0.9
  bouncy-castle-java-1.5.0147
  coffee-script-source-1.6.2
  execjs-1.4.0
  coffee-script-2.2.0
  rack-ssl-1.3.3
  json-1.8.0-java
  rdoc-3.12.2
  thor-0.18.1
  railties-3.2.13
  coffee-rails-3.2.2
  faker-1.1.2
  httpi-2.0.2
  jquery-rails-2.2.2
  jruby-openssl-0.8.8
  nori-2.1.0
  rails-3.2.13
  sass-rails-3.2.6
  wasabi-3.1.0
  savon-2.2.0
  therubyrhino_jar-1.7.4
  therubyrhino-2.0.2
  uglifier-1.0.4
  uuidtools-2.1.4

--- Bundler
Bundler.bundle_path: /opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/myDomain/applications/web-admin/WEB-INF/gems
Bundler.root: /opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/myDomain/applications/web-admin/WEB-INF
Gemfile: /opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/myDomain/applications/web-admin/WEB-INF/Gemfile
Settings:
  gemfile = /opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/myDomain/applications/web-admin/WEB-INF/Gemfile
  without = development:test:assets
  bin_path = /opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/myDomain/applications/web-admin/WEB-INF/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle

--- JRuby-Rack Config
compat_version = 
default_logger = org.jruby.rack.logging.StandardOutLogger@62a49a04
equals = 
err = com.sun.common.util.logging.LoggingOutputStream$LoggingPrintStream@7a21bdb8
filter_adds_html = true
filter_verifies_resource = false
ignore_environment = false
initial_memory_buffer_size = 
initial_runtimes = 
jms_connection_factory = 
jms_jndi_properties = 
logger = org.jruby.rack.logging.ServletContextLogger@19a2312c
logger_class_name = servlet_context
logger_name = jruby.rack
maximum_memory_buffer_size = 
maximum_runtimes = 
num_initializer_threads = 
out = com.sun.common.util.logging.LoggingOutputStream$LoggingPrintStream@52f8d395
rackup = 
rackup_path = 
rewindable = true
runtime_arguments = 
runtime_environment = 
runtime_timeout_seconds = 
serial_initialization = false
servlet_context = org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade@16c7e149
throw_init_exception = false
|#]

[#|2013-05-31T17:10:25.182-0400|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC1412: WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():DEBUG: resetting rack response due exception|#]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with source code control. My helpers directory was not added and therefore Jenkins was not including in the build. Always check the obvious first, if it says it isn't there it probably isn't.